# SSRS Databar (Reporting Services)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'm using SSRS 2010 against an OLAP 2012 datasource.

I have two datasets at different granularities with with a logical join.  I have a matrix based on one dataset I and want to add an inline databar to the matrix that's based on the other dataset.  Is it possible to do this and limit the data in the databar based on the key value in the respective matrix row?

Also, is there a way to make the graphic within the cell appear wider?  If I stretch the column very wide, the chart within it is still tiny.

Comment: Can you not use Lookup() to look up the values from one dataset to the other? Please can you supply a image of the latter.

Comment: Oh! I've never used the Lookup() function. Thanks, I'll give that a shot. Would I need to use LookupSet() or just Lookup()? I think the 2nd issue was caused by excessive Calendar members in the series with no associated data. It looks much better now that the dataset is only returning relevant years.

Comment: I don't know which with out seeing the form I'm afraid. I've used Lookup extensively but not LookupSet.

Comment: Thanks, Preet. I'll look into Lookup()!